# Obtain Network Credentials from Current User in Windows Authentication Application

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, axapta, business-connector

I was wondering whether it was possible to obtain the current user object and get their credentials so that I can pass them along to a `NetworkCredential` object which I am using to connect to my AX .NET Business Connector. As, at the moment I'm having to specify it connect as a specific user which I set when I instantiate a `NetworkCredential` object:

`private NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("myUser", "myPassword", "myDomain");`

I was hoping to do something like: `private NetworkCredential nc = (NetworkCredential)HttpContext.User;` but obviously that won't work...

That way, it's easier to keep track of which user has created a sales order for example, as at the moment everything gets created by the user I have specified..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx)?

> The credentials returned by `DefaultNetworkCredentials` represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application.

Comment: When I used this, the credential are all empty strings?

Comment: It returns a `SystemNetworkCredential`, an internal class that derives from `NetworkCredential`. There's hidden magic inside it, but it deliberately sets the username, password, etc as empty strings, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Well, I cant use this way anyway as I wanted to pass the object along to a WCF Web service.. but seems this is not possible.. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 5):

I don't fully understand your question, but is your call coming from ASP.NET that you require the credentials?  You could attempt:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
```

Assuming your user has already authenticated via a Membership Provider.

Comment: I'm using an ASP.NET MVC 3 Windows Authentication application, so I assume they've been authenticated? When I look at `credential` all of the fields are empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the above worked great for me to resolve the authentication.

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential();
ICredentials credent = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
credentials = (NetworkCredential)credent;
var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(GlobalVariables.LDAPServer);

LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials);
connection.Bind();
```