# How to take OS Windows session credentials?

Tags: c++

I need to implement a feature to take user session credentials.
Then to use them to authorize in a proxy server.

It should be implemented the same way as in the VMware vSphere Client.

I tried to use CredWrite/CredRead but CredRead works only for the names produced by CredWrite call.

Can you help me to understand how to do that or give me an article describing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not a security expert but if this were possible, a virus would have an easy life.

Comment: Anyway, you might take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414266/obtain-network-credentials-from-current-user-in-windows-authentication-applicati

Comment: Thanks. I forget to say that I need C/C++ api...